# RabbitMQ Listening to a queue from multiple servers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I need to realize listening from a queue from two servers. The queue name is the same. The first server is the primary, the second is the backup.
When the main server is down, work with the backup server queue should continue.

My class:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "to_client")
public class ClientRabbitService {
```

Now I use RoutingConnectionFactory:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ConnectionFactory routingConnectionFactory() {
    SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory rcf = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
    Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("[to_kernel]", mainConnectionFactory());
    map.put("[to_kernel_reserve]", reserveConnectionFactory());
    map.put("[to_client]", mainConnectionFactory());

    rcf.setTargetConnectionFactories(map);

    return rcf;
}
```

[to_kernel] and [to_kernel_reserve] - the queues for sending messages only, [to_client] - to receive them.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Is the queue on backup server populated only when primary server is down? If yes you may always listen to both queues (queue on secondary server will be empty when primary is up).

Note that your solution would be more reliable if you use RabbitMQ clustering.
Then, you connect to the cluster (you specify addresses of all machines in cluster).

It is explained in official documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#connections

> Alternatively, if running in a clustered environment, use the
>   addresses attribute.
>
> ```
> <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" addresses="host1:5672,host2:5672"/>
> ```

When using cluster you will have single queue (replicated across cluster). Note that RabbitMQ suffers significant performance hit when using replication, be sure to read official documentation how to configure clustering https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html